# How to change List item icon using a function in kivymd?

Tags: python, icons, kivymd

I am a beginner in kivymd. I was trying to create a functionality in my project. In this I need to change icon of OneLineIconListItem as well as its text. I can easily change the the text. But still unable to change the icon. Here is the portion of my problem from code.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem,IconLeftWidget

KV = """
MDScreen:
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint : {"center_x": 0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
        MDList:
            OneLineIconListItem:
                id: control_panel
                text: 'Message'
                
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon:'android-messages'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "change"
        user_font_size: "30sp"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        on_release: 
            app.demoFunction()
"""

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen

    def demoFunction(self):
        self.root.ids.control_panel.text = 'Control panel'
        self.root.ids.control_panel.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon='account'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoApp().run()
```

When I press the button the Icon is not changing, it is adding a new icon. How can I change the icon on pressing the button?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem,IconLeftWidget

KV = """
MDScreen:
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint : {"center_x": 0.5, 'center_y':0.3}
        MDList:
            OneLineIconListItem:
                id: control_panel
                text: 'Message'
                
                IconLeftWidget:
                    id: jbsidis
                    icon:'android-messages'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "change"
        user_font_size: "30sp"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        on_release: 
            app.demoFunction()
"""

class DemoAppjbsidis(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen

    def demoFunction(self):
        if self.root.ids.jbsidis.icon=="android-messages":
            self.root.ids.jbsidis.icon="account"
            self.root.ids.control_panel.text="New text hereee, icon is account"
            return 0
        if self.root.ids.jbsidis.icon=="account":
            self.root.ids.jbsidis.icon="android-messages"
            self.root.ids.control_panel.text="New text hereee, icon is android-messages"
            return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoAppjbsidis().run()
```

Pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are so cool, Thank you very much.